# Can't seem to insert a link on top of image

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

Here's the website in question: http://remarkabledigital.com/

The top of the website features a full width image.  In the image there's a tablet device with some text and a "contact-us" button.

I wanted to make the "contact-us" button clickable via a link.

I've tried putting an anchor tag on top of the image, but it's not clickable.
I've tried declaring and area map, but it's not clickable.
I've tried putting an anchor tag around the ENTIRE bloody image, but it's not clickable.
I've also tried assigning an "onclick" to the image (which is what the code states right now), but that doesn't work either.

I must be missing something quite simple here.  It seems like the image is "blocking" the ability for other elements to function.

Any HTML gurus out there?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the container is in the background below everything else.

Change the style.css entry for `.title-card`

From:

```
.title-card {
   z-index: -1;
}
```

To:

```
.title-card {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Which will make your image's onclick event clickable.

Update:
Additionally need to apply it to the image as well to work in other browsers (IE).

```
.title-card > img.header-img {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Alternatively remove any reference to `z-index: -1;` in style.css

Comment: I've updated the CSS to reflect your changes, but I'm still not able to get a link to be clickable... I've added an anchor tag to surround the "contact-us" part of the image, but it's not working.

Comment: @Trevor The image has a `position: absolute; z-index: 1`. If the `a` element has the same `z-index` and is after `img` the img will take priority and cover the link. Move the anchor above the `img` element and add `position: relative;z-index: 2;` to the anchor's style. eg: `<a style="position: relative;z-index:2;">test</a><img />` Additionally to fix your site banner set `#site-meta{ z-index: 2; }` in `style.css`.

Comment: @Trevor Evaluate your entire site's `z-index` ordering to ensure elements are layered appropriately. Any negative z-index will result in the element being behind the `html/body/page` and elements that do not have a z-index specifically set. The result will render differently in different browsers. EG: at the top of style.css `* {z-index: 0;}` to force all elements to start off at base level/auto z-index.

Comment: @Trevor also keep in mind, the image you are attempting to add a link to is being repositioned dynamically and is not displayed unless javascript is enabled.

Comment: Thanks so much @Fyrye, I switched the anchor tag to be before the img, changed the `z-index` to `2` and added the `postition: relative` as well and it fixed the problem!

Comment: If you want to add those details to your original post, I can mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @Trevor The issue you were experiencing with an element being `not clickable` was resolved with the `z-index` fix supplied in the answer with the code you supplied at time of the question's submission. Proper element order and css style troubleshooting would be outside of the scope of your original question and shouldn't be included in the answer, since you altered the code `I've also tried assigning an "onclick" to the image (which is what the code states right now)` and thus the question.